Why is the electric field inside a conducting filled/hollow sphere is zero?

why is the electric field inside a conducting filled/hollow sphere is zero, when a charge emits electric field lines radially?

The linked answers are good, but I am not sure if they speak to what you are asking. In the space between a charge and the inner surface of a hollow conducting sphere, the field is not $0$. It is $0$ inside the condutor, the space bewteen the inner and outer surfaces of the conductor.
